# SQL sessions start failing at night when the traffic is less

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, mybatis

My team is facing an issue where our SQL session fails to `insert`/`update`/`delete` at night when the traffic is less.

Our code works perfectly during the day. At night what happens is we're able to get a `SQLsession` but when we run queries on it, it fails.

Our code is something like this:

```java
SqlSession sqlSession = openSession();
// successful in getting an open session
FooMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(FooMapper.class);
// Gets the mapper
FooMapper.insert(Foo);
// prepares the SQL statement successfully
sqlSession.commit()
// FAILS
```

Error in logs:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 810,878 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 810,880 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

MyBatis properties:

```
"ssl", "false"
"poolPingQuery", "/* ping */ SELECT 1"
"poolPingEnabled", "true"
"poolPingConnectionsNotUsedFor", 20000 + ""
"poolMaximumActiveConnections", Integer.toString(25)
"poolMaximumIdleConnections", Integer.toString(10)
"allowPublicKeyRetrieval","true"
```

Please help

**UPDATE 1**: I dived deep into the server logs. Basically our wait_timeout is set to 500 seconds and all the times this error occurred it was beyond 500s so what I understand is that our mysql server is killing these connections but mybatis is not removing them from it's pool and that's why this issue is arising. But we're unable to understand when we're pinging every idle connection every 20 seconds how can a connection be idle for more than wait_timeout and be killed?

Comment: Any maintanance job running at night? (like backup, reindexing, etc...)

Comment: Maintenance jobs are running for about 12 hours whereas this issue happens at the absolute dead of the night when the traffic is super low.

Comment: I think this is something related to my server storing stale connections which the sql server has already killed (wait_timeout).

Comment: sorry, i am not an expert in mysql nor spring (my stack is .net and mssql), so I am shooting from the hip: by any chance, is (your?) `openSession();` recycling one connection? (You know, something like "SqlConnection is singleton for us" - and thats wrong and thats pretty common mistake - there is (should be :) ) sql connection pooling integrated in your framework of choice. Creating connection is ultra cheap becouse of this & it should solve stale connections). But I have no idea why it should show up just at night, so take it with grain of salt...

Comment: For whatever reason we had to use `4999` as the largest number we could get working (never looked more into it) as well, we aren't using mysql, and just do the plain `select 1`.  You should be able to debug and see mybatis logging that every few minutes?

Comment: @kendavidson 4999 for which property?

Comment: I dived deep into the server logs. Basically our wait_timeout is set to 500 seconds and all the times this error occurred it was beyond  500s so what I understand is that our mysql server is killing these connections but mybatis is not removing them from it's pool and that's why this issue is arising. But we're unable to understand when we're pinging every idle connection every 20 seconds how can a connection be idle for more than wait_timeout and be killed?

Comment: Sorry, for `poolPingConnectionsNotUsedFor` (my bad).  Also just using a regular query (not /* ping */ included) for `poolPingQuery`.  But again, we don't use Mysql and don't have the ping option, but worth trying I guess.  Maybe something up with that version of Mysql driver.

Comment: @AkG What's the MyBatis version? This should not happen in the recent versions, I believe. Try the latest version if you haven't.

Comment: @ave We're using mybatis 3.2.2